# How to subclass a frozen dataclass

Tags: python, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I have inherited the `Customer` dataclass. This identifies a customer in the customer DB table.

`Customer` is used to produce summary statistics for transactions pertaining to a given customer. It is hashable, hence frozen.

I require a `SpecialCustomer` (a subclass of `Customer`) it has an extra property: `special_property`. Most of the properties inherited from `Customer` will be set to fixed values. This customer does not exist in the Customer table.

I wish to utilise code which has been written for `Customer`. Without `special_property` we will not be able to distinguish between special customers.

How do I instantiate `SpecialCustomer`?

Here is what I have. I know why this doesn't work. Is there some way to do this?:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class Customer:
    property: str


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class SpecialCustomer(Customer):

    special_property: str = Field(init=False)

    def __init__(self, special_property):
        super().__init__(property="dummy_value")
        self.special_property = special_property

s = SpecialCustomer(special_property="foo")
```

Error:

```
E   dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'special_property'

<string>:4: FrozenInstanceError
```

Comment: 1) Do you actually need _nominal_ inheritance or would it be enough for `SuperMan` to be a _structural_ subtype of `Man` (while also satisfying all your other requirements)? 2) Unrelated to question 1, what is the idea behind excluding `unique` from the init method, but then trivially setting it there anyway? There must be some additional purpose for this that you did not mention as to why you wouldn't just add `unique`as a normal field.

Comment: Man is a hashable DTO. SuperMan needs to set a bunch of boilerplate fields in Man which the user shouldn't know about. Unique is a variable that the user sets. The final object will be used a function which requires an instance of Man

Comment: Does not really answer my 2nd question: Why can't `unique` just be a normal field, if all you do is take it as an `__init__` argument and set the value as a normal attribute? Also: _"boilerplate fields in `Man` which the user shouldn't know about"_ But the user _will_ know about them, if they are fields of `Man` and `SuperMan` inherits from it. There is no way to "hide" them. So maybe you want to expand your post to provide additional context because this is starting to seem more and more like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I have rephrased the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not like this?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass as pydantic_dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class Customer:
    prop: str


@pydantic_dataclass(frozen=True, order=True, kw_only=True)
class SpecialCustomer(Customer):
    special_prop: str
    prop: str = "dummy_value"


print(SpecialCustomer(special_prop="foo"))
```

Output: `SpecialCustomer(prop='dummy_value', special_prop='foo')`

Problem is that without `kw_only=True` we cannot have a non-default field after a default one and with the weird approach taken by dataclasses, `prop` is still considered *before* `special_prop`, even though it is re-declared after it...

Dataclasses are just very restrictive. Basically, if you want anything other vanilla, you'll have a bad time. If you were willing/able to switch to something like [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) instead, those are much more flexible and also lightweight. Normal Pydantic models too of course, but they are less light-weight.

---

If the problem with my suggested solution is that it still allows users of the `SpecialCustomer` class to set arbitrary values for `prop`, you could prevent that with an additional check in [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing). That would of course be annoying, if there are many fields that should be fixed, but I fail to see any other way to construct this.

Something like this:

```py
...

@pydantic_dataclass(frozen=True, order=True, kw_only=True)
class SpecialCustomer(Customer):
    special_prop: str
    prop1: str = "dummy_value"
    prop2: int = 123
    prop3: tuple[float, float] = (3.14, 0.)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        assert self.prop1 == "dummy_value"
        assert self.prop2 == 123
        assert self.prop3 == (3.14, 0.)


print(SpecialCustomer(special_prop="foo"))
try:
    SpecialCustomer(prop1="something", special_prop="bar")
except AssertionError as e:
    print("No! Bad user.")
```

Alternatively, since this is a Pydantic class, you could define [validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) for the fixed fields that do essentially the same thing.

---

### PS: Possible `attrs` solution

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from attrs import define, field


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class Customer:
    prop1: str
    prop2: int
    prop3: tuple[float, float]


@define(frozen=True, order=True)
class SpecialCustomer(Customer):
    prop1: str = field(default="dummy_value", init=False)
    prop2: int = field(default=123, init=False)
    prop3: tuple[float, float] = field(default=(3.14, 0.), init=False)
    special_prop: str


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json
    from attrs import asdict
    s = SpecialCustomer("foo")
    print(json.dumps(asdict(s), indent=4))
    print(isinstance(s, Customer))
    print(hash(s))
    try:
        SpecialCustomer(prop1="abc", special_prop="bar")
    except TypeError as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Output:

```
{
    "prop1": "dummy_value",
    "prop2": 123,
    "prop3": [
        3.14,
        0.0
    ],
    "special_prop": "foo"
}
True
6587449294214520366
TypeError("SpecialCustomer.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prop1'")
```

Comment: Thank you. How would the attrs solution look like?

Comment: @GlaceCelery I added an example with `attrs`.