Pydantic dataclasses: Is it possible to use inheritance with default fields
I am trying to use pydantic frozen dataclasses to create stable and validated data structures. In the process, it seemed like my code would benefit from using inheritance because a lot of methods were shared between multiple objects.
My question is the following, is there a way to use inheritance to define a parent class that has default fields, while the child class includes non-default ones. Using dataclass(frozen=True) is important to ensure easy serialisation.
The example is the following, I'm creating a parent class A and a child B. A has both default and non-default arguments. The main interest here is having the field A.y that is initialised by the validator using other fields that already passed validation. B requires initialisation of non-default fields.
Note that there are in reality multiple child classes that also share methods with A, that part not causing any issue with pydantic.
from pydantic import field_validator, Field, ValidationInfo
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
    x: int
    y: int = Field(default=0, init=False, validate_default=True, repr=False)

    @field_validator("x")
    def validate_x(cls, x):
        if x < 0:
            raise ValueError("x must be non-negative")
        return x

    @field_validator("y", mode="after")
    def validate_y(cls, y, info=ValidationInfo):
        y = info.data["x"] + 1
        return y
    
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class B(A):
    name: str
    z: int = Field(default=0, init=False, validate_default=True, repr=False)

    @field_validator("z")
    def validate_z(cls, z, info=ValidationInfo):
        z = info.data["x"] + info.data["y"]
        return z
    
b = B(x=1, name="name")
print(b)

This returns the following error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../new_file.py", line 21, in <module>
    class B(A):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/qcd/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/dataclasses.py", line 225, in create_dataclass
    cls = dataclasses.dataclass(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/qcd/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 1184, in dataclass
    return wrap(cls)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/qcd/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 1175, in wrap
    return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash,
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/qcd/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 1024, in _process_class
    _init_fn(all_init_fields,
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/qcd/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 544, in _init_fn
    raise TypeError(f'non-default argument {f.name!r} '
TypeError: non-default argument 'name' follows default argument

which I guess is a default python error raised because pydantic automatic __init__ puts arguments in order and a default argument is written before a non-default one.
My main issue until now is that I can't assign new fields after validation, and hopefully I can also avoid writing validators for each child.
Is there a way to circumvent this issue?

The problem can be reproduced also without those three field validators that account for approx. half of the code lines. Please try to make the posted code minimal. More people will be willing to read it.

Please read about the kw_only=True option in the child dataclass here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75420274/5378816. The example will work without an error. Does it solve your case?
